# Do not write None or empty lines in Spark (Python)

Tags: python, hadoop, apache-spark, pyspark

I am new in Spark, but I have had some experience in Hadoop. I've trying to adapt a python code I use in Hadoop streaming that filters out some tweets in JSON format.

Normally, my function has a condition that prints to stdout the tweet if the condition is true and prints nothing otherwise.

```
def filter(tweet):
   if criteria(tweet) is True:
      print json.dumps(tweet)
```

This way, the final output file will contain only the tweets I want.

However, when trying to use Spark, I had to change the `print` statement with a `return` so I return the tweet if the condition is True, and `None` otherwise.

```
def filter(tweet):
       if criteria(tweet) is True:
          return json.dumps(tweet)
```

The problem appears when trying to save the results to disk. Using `saveAsTextFile` method of Pyspark, it saves not only the tweets I want but also the `None` I return when condition is False.

How can I avoid writing `None` to the file so I only save the desired tweets?

Many thanks in advance.

Jorge

Comment: Why can't you just else return "" ?  If that doesn't work you can't do some simple post processing for the returned json dump?

Comment: Hi free_mind. That's a good point but Is it not going to print a empty line instead?..... Will try just in case. Thank you for your response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quite elegant solution, which avoids chaining `filter` and `map`, is to use `flatMap`:

```
def filter(tweet):
    return [json.dumps(tweet)] if criteria(tweet) is True else []

some_rdd.flatMap(filter)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using your function in a map, it will not reduce the number of elements you have. To filter elements, you must to use the `filter` method to test if an element is `None` after you `map`.